# object conversion c++; int's to double

Tags: c++, data-conversion

I'm new to c++ and am stumped on object conversion. Basically, I have a class with two integers members and I want to write a member conversion function in order to end up with a double. However, each time I run the program I get a integer returned (specifically 0). Here's my work.

From the .h

```
class FieldGoal
{
  private:
      int fieldGoals;
      int attempts;
  public:
      FieldGoal()
          {fieldGoals = attempts = 0;}
      FieldGoal(int, int);
      operator double();  
};
```

Function Definitions from .cpp

```
FieldGoal::FieldGoal(int f, int a)
{
    fieldGoals = f;
    attempts = a;
}

FieldGoal::operator double()
{
    return fieldGoals/attempts;
}
```

And the program creating the object and calling functions.

```
int main()
{
    FieldGoal myPlays(20,50);
    double percentage = myPlays;
    cout << percentage << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm confused as to what your goal is for the output?

Comment: 20/50 = 0.4 That's what I want but get 0.

Comment: An operator that implicitly converts `FieldGoal` to `double` is probably not a good idea. Reserve such operators for classes that act like numbers. If you can't add two objects of type `FieldGoal`, you don't want the implicit conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was confused on the conversion process. I thought it was something built into C++ that recognized *operator double()* syntax and would do the conversion for me. Turns out, I had to actually convert the int's to doubles in the function and then return it.

I'm not sure what the advantages of converting objects data types this way are. Hopefully it makes sense as I go on.

Here I converted them to doubles by first dividing the integers by 1.0.

```
FieldGoal::operator double()
{
    return (fieldGoals/1.0)/(attempts/1.0);
}
```

Comment: `static_cast<double>(fieldGoals)` is the preferred way to convert an `int` to `double`.

Comment: You may also want to check for the divide by zero condition in your operator method implementation.

Answer (score 0):

So a few revisions need to be made to your code. First, it is important to understand that `double()` is not an `operator`, and if you want to convert an int to a double, don't overthink it!

Consider these revisions:

Create a public member function that returns your desired double:

```
class FieldGoal
{
      ...
      double my_function();  // <----
};
```

Cast your result and make sure it returns a double:

```
double FieldGoal::my_function()
{
    return (double) fieldGoals/attempts; // <---- 
}
```

Make sure you *call* your function when assigning the double:

```
int main()
{
    FieldGoal myPlays(20,50);
    double percentage = myPlays.my_function(); // <----
    cout << percentage << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is the ideal implementation. However, what I'm trying to do is for a class and the point is to learn object conversion.

Comment: Also I should point out that I wasn't implying that the data type "double" is an operator, rather the function I'm creating is an "operator function" that converts data types.

Comment: `operator double()` is perfectly valid C++.